Parsing Error in IBM Cognos Query Calculation
I'm receiving an error code called "QE-DEF-0459 CCLException" "QE-DEF-0260 Parsing error before or near position 110:" in a query calculation for IBM cognos. I want to use this query to take one date in our DB and use it to push a variable date that will change based on the month of my first variable (Original Date) The main difficulty that has been preventing me from resolving this issue is my own inexperience with the IBM cognos platform. My code is attached below, so if there are any obvious solutions that I have missed please let me know!
CASE
    WHEN [OriginalDate] IS NOT NULL THEN
        CAST(
            DATEADD(
                MONTH,
                1,
                DATEADD(
                    DAY,
                    -DAY([OriginalDate]) + 1,
                    [OriginalDate]
                )
            ) AS DATE
        )
    ELSE NULL
END AS [NewDate]

I tried asking co-pilot to explain the error, but I came away with little useful information. It has been a while since I have used SQL to write queries, but hopefully I can regain some proficiency as I gain experience w/ Cognos. Thanks!

Just use CASE WHEN [OriginalDate] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST( DATEADD( MONTH, 1, DATEADD( DAY, -DAY([OriginalDate]) + 1, [OriginalDate] ) ) AS DATE ) ELSE NULL END  and leave the AS [NEWDATE] off.  You will get this for free as the name of the query item.   It should not be a part of the expression itself.

This isn't a SQL question, it's a Cognos question.  And as for Copilot:  Put in a bit more effort.  Don't post here after your only attempt to solve a problem was to ask an AI to do your job.  Until you put forth some effort, you are unlikely to get help.

And, yes, I can identify the three things that are definitely wrong with this code, plus one other that causes some concern.  And there is one other item that may be a problem, depending on your environment, once those first three or four items are fixed.

To get help here, it's important to follow some basic guidelines, for example https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
